# Problema con controladores al cambiar de vista con JavaFx y Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, javafx, spring-boot

He creado una aplicación con Spring Boot y Javafx en la que todo funciona sin problema y puedo navegar entre las diferentes pestañas y sus respectivos controladores sin problemas, por que estan integrados un una sola vista.

El problema surge cuando añado una ventana inicial de Login, para acceder a la vista general anteriormente comentada.

Mi codigo en el controlador del Login para cargar la vista principal es:

```
    @FXML
 public void login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Principal.fxml"));
    loader.load();
    Parent p = ((FXMLLoader) loader.getRoot()).load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(p));

    stage.show();

}
```

El error que arroja es "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" cuando intenta acceder a los servicios inyectados con @Autowired.

Parece como si se perdiese la configuración de Spring Boot al acceder a esta vista.

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver más detalles no estoy seguro al 100%, pero parece que:

- Creas un objeto (o FXMLLoader lo crea por ti).
- Spring no ha creado dicha instancia, por tanto no sabe de su existencia y no inyectará ninguna dependencia.

La solución sería inyectarle desde tu clase principal los servicios *manualmente*.

Comment: si, pero busco una manera de que gestione spring las dependencias. No se como podría hacer que la configuración se extienda a esta vista

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

Me faltaba añadirle al FXMLLoader:

```
loader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
```